# How do I create dummy variables for a subset of a categorical variable?

Tags: python, pandas

### Example

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
>>> s
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: object
>>> pd.get_dummies(s)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

Now I would like to map `a` and `b` to a dummy variable, but nothing else. How can I do that?

### What I tried

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(s, columns=['a', 'b'])
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

Comment: Would you want `pd.get_dummies(s[s.isin(list('ab'))])`? this drops row 2

Comment: No, I want to keep all rows. If the value is not in the provided ones, then there simply is `0` for the provided columns (an "other" column would be nice for that cases - this is the reason why I will not accept my current answer)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler method is to just mask the resultant df with the cols of interest:

```
In[16]:
pd.get_dummies(s)[list('ab')]

Out[16]: 
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
```

So this will sub-select the resultant dummies df with the cols of interest

If you don't want to calculate the dummies column for the columns that you are not interested in the first place, then you could filter out the rows of interest but this requires `reindex`ing with a [`fill_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) (thanks to @jezrael for the suggestion):

```
In[20]:
pd.get_dummies(s[s.isin(list('ab'))]).reindex(s.index, fill_value=0)

Out[20]: 
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
```

Comment: I like your second solution - it should be more efficient.

Comment: `.reindex(s.index, fill_value=0)` should be better

Comment: @jezrael yes that is much cleaner, I forgot you could specify the fill value with `reindex` will update

Answer (score 0):

Setting everything else to nan is one option:

```
s[~((s == 'a') | (s == 'b'))] = float('nan')
```

which yields:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(s)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
In [3907]: pd.DataFrame({c:s.eq(c).astype(int) for c in ['a', 'b']})
Out[3907]:
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
```

Or, `(s==c).astype(int)`